# colorcolum only in certain files (e.g. *.cpp, *.h) in VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to have a marker at column 80 in VIM, but only in file like *.cpp, *.h. but not in *.txt

For now I have this in my .vimrc

```
set cc=120
```

Cheers

**Solution**:

```
autocmd FileType cpp,c,cxx,h,hpp,python,sh  setlocal cc=120
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim doesn't directly use the file extension, it has an indirection called `filetype`, which is then used for syntax highlighting and specific settings.

Put your `:set` command (as `:setlocal`, so that it only affects the current buffer [1]) in a new file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`. (You could also use `:autocmd FileType cpp setlocal cc=120` directly in your `.vimrc`, but the separation is cleaner once you do a lot of that customization.)

---

[1] Note that `'colorcolumn'` is window-local, not buffer-local, so the approach isn't perfect, but usually good enough. It can be perfected with additional `BufWinEnter/Leave` autocmds.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Well, I tried 'set cc=80' in '~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim' and opened a file 'vim bla.cpp'

Comment: Does your filetype detection work, i.e. does `:set ft?` print `cpp`? Otherwise, you need `:filetype plugin on` in your `.vimrc`. Then, check with `:scriptnames` that the new script has actually been sourced.

Comment: Ok, must have missed the detail of the need of a plugin. I prefer not to use plugins, though if there won't be any other answer I'll give you the ok.

Comment: The _filetype_ plugins that ship with Vim mostly only set some reasonable settings; we're not talking about big enhancements like other plugins do here. Anyway, if you prefer to keep ftplugins turned off, just use the `:autocmd FileType cpp setlocal cc=120` in your `.vimrc`.